# How to copy correctly all contents of Map having key Object and value object into ArrayList in java

Tags: java

I am trying to copy all elements of my map (`result.getBits`) into an `ArrayList` of `RootSearchItem` object.

I can not get the totality of my map entry into my `ArrayList` by doing the code below. Can someone help me please?

My Object RootSearchItem:

```
public class RootSearchItem {
    @XmlElement
    private SearchType searchType;
    @XmlElement
    private CustomBitSet bits = new CustomBitSet();
    ......
}
```

MY CODE:

```
for (Map.Entry<SearchType, CustomBitSet> pair : result.getBits().entrySet()) {
    RootSearchItem rsi = new RootSearchItem(pair.getKey(),false,pair.getValue().getBitsDataLongArray());
    if (!rootSearchItemList1.contains(rsi)) {
        rootSearchItemList1.add(rsi);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify the exact issue that you are facing?

Comment: Actually, when I iterate my map and add my element into my list, at the end of the iteration, I realize the my list doesn t contain the exact element contents that I have in my map. My map contains 5 elements and my list as well but the object contents are not the same. It may be due to a copy of an object to another object???

Comment: do you have duplicate objects? you can add lot of print statements in between you code to understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: I do not have a duplicate objects. But my list object value(CustomBitSet), doesn t contain the same values as my object list